# AutoMapperMappingExtensions was unhandled by user

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper, automapper-2

I'm developing an applications, it involves a dropdownlist with image and text in MVC4. For instance, displaying image (Country Flag) with name of the country. I've used AutoMapper, IEnumerable. It says error as **AutoMapperMappingExtensions was unhandled by user**.

Description as

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
Country -> ImageSelectListItem
MvcWebRole.Models.Country -> System.Web.Mvc.Html.ImageSelectListItem

Destination path:
IEnumerable`1[0]

Source value:
MvcWebRole.Models.Country
```

The occurance of error in 
*Controller* as

```cs
Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Country>, IEnumerable<ImageSelectListItem>>(countryList)
```

*index.cshtml*

```
@Html.DropDownListFor
```

In cshtml error description as

```
The type arguments for method
'System.Web.Mvc.html.ImageselectExtensions.dropdownlistfo<TModel,TProperty> (
    System.Web.mvc.htmlhelper<TModel>,
    System.Linq.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TProperty>>,
    string,
    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.Html.ImageSelectListItem>,
    Object)'
cannot be inferred from the usage. Try Specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

Comment: That error says you're missing some mapping configuration. If possible, please show the mapping you have currently defined. Thx

Comment: You're going to have to provide more information.  You need to provide the Mapping configuration and the definition of Country.